# multiple simultaneous connections on same jupyter notebook at the same time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I created a jupyter notebook with the purpose of taking a survey on a fairly large group of people, which consists of 1 script that each person has to run and fill in. To make it convenient for them I hosted a public jupyter notebook server and mailed every person the link to participate.

The problem is that when one person is running the script, all other people have to wait until that person closes the notebook in order for them to run it. I want a system that generates one seperate kernel for every incoming connection so multiple people can take the survey at the same time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Jupyter Notebook wasn't made for simultaneous collaboration on the same file. One solution I've seen that addresses exactly this problem is [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), which is a fork of Jupyter built on Google's collaborative Docs platform, and allows exactly what you're talking about.

It looks like for Jupyter Lab, they're hoping to integrate simultaneous editing as a core feature (they were originally going for a Google Drive backend, but Google seems to have pulled support and now they're considering more P2P solutions like IPFS), but it looks like that work has [hit a few roadbumps and won't be released with version 1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/qDANqdaeXUo).

Comment: seems like a great solution, however my survey script is using matplotlib nbag to make an interactive plot where people can click on certain parts of the graph to place flags, which doesn't seem to work in colab (no output). Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: I presume you already tried `!pip install nbag` or whatever the module name is to make sure the module's installed? You could see if any other interactive plotting frameworks are supported on Colab (such as plotly or bokeh) besides mpl nbag. Otherwise, this is still a very new domain under active development, so maybe submit a feature request of bug report to Google Colab and see if they can help you out.